# Grouping by Id but grabbing first date related to the Id

Tags: sql

Goal: Get unique MembershipId's and the first date related to the MembershipId.

I can get the distinct MembershipId, but I am not sure of the best way to grab the date that is related to the record.

IE.

```
1 : 12/1/12
1 : 12/2/12
2 : 12/1/12
3 : 12/1/12
```

Should Return

```
1 : 12/1/12
2 : 12/1/12
3 : 12/1/12
```

The dates don't really matter about being the same day it was just easy to type that way, what is important is it returned the Id as 1 and the first date related with that record.

I am meshing 2 tables into a temp table, then selecting the distinct Ids but I am stumped how to get the related dates.

Here is what I have so far:

```
select [MembershipId], [DateCreated]
INTO #StripeTemp
FROM fundingsources

UNION

select [UserId] as MembershipId, [DateInserted] as DateCreated
FROM FundingSourceCustomer

select distinct MembershipId
from #StripeTemp

Drop table #StripeTemp
```

Comment: Do you want the **earliest** date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a basic aggregation query, I think.  This is the version for one table:

```
select [MembershipId], min([DateCreated]) as FirstDateCreated
INTO #StripeTemp
FROM fundingsources
GROUP BY MembershipID;
```

This assumes that `DateCreated` is actually stored as a `date` or `datetime`.

You can do this for two tables by using `union all` in a subquery, so temporary tables are not necessary:

```
select [MembershipId], min([DateCreated]) as FirstDateCreated
FROM (select MemberShipId, DateCreated
      from fundingsources
      union all
      select MemberShipId, DateInserted
      from fundingsourcecustomer
     ) t
GROUP BY MembershipID;
```

Comment: Holy crap, I ended up figuring out a solution but it was much longer and complicated than this. This is good stuff man thank you for the help it worked like a charm!

Comment: You know, I initially did the grouping, and I had the min(datecreated) but the problem I had was I put the date in the group by clause as well. Thanks again this was really helpful and educational!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the number of rows per id it might be more efficient to pre-aggregate before the UNION:

```
SELECT MembershipId, MIN(DateCreated) AS FirstDateCreated
FROM (SELECT MembershipId, MIN(DateCreated) AS DateCreated
      FROM fundingsources
      GROUP BY MembershipId 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT MembershipId, MIN(DateCreated) AS DateCreated
      FROM fundingsourcecustomer
      GROUP BY MembershipId 
     ) t
GROUP BY MembershipID;
```